# Is there any way to get list of databases from a remote db2 database instance?

Tags: db2

I have runtime client for db2 v10.5. I want to know that is there any way that WITHOUT CAT LOGGING remote databases into my client, I can get list of databases from a remote instance?

Comment: The DAS performs this action, because when configuring with the db2ca, it detects the instances of a remore machine. However, there is not a public or known API to do the "discovery request". There are several parameters to configure the behaviour when these requests occurs: discover, discover_inst, discover_db

Answer (score -2):

Please Try:

```
db2 list db directory
```

Comment: If you execute this on a remote client it will list the databases that have been cataloged on the *client*, not the databases that exist on the *server*.